# What does it mean when d|n is in the lower bound of a sum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

More specifically, what does it mean when you see this
$\sum_{d|n}$ in Number Theory?

Comment: It means "sum over all positive divisors $d$ of $n$". You should have searched the site a bit for this.

Comment: I did, I just didn't know how to phrase it correctly.

Comment: E.g. $\sum_{d|6}d =1+2+3+6 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal notation:
$$\sum_{d|n}$$
is used to refer to a sum iterated on all divisors $d$ of $n$.
For example, the function $\sigma(n)$ is defined as follows:
$$\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n}d$$
And the generalised $\sigma$ function:
$$\sigma_{\alpha}(n)=\sum_{d|n}d^{\alpha}$$

Comment: @Daniel Waters: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $1$ or a favourite answer?